# Override the excel file name of soap ui project through pom

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui

I have a SOAP UI PRO project and I am using maven-soapui-pro-plugin and configured the maven project in jenkins. The SOAP UI project retrieves data from an Excel DataSource and executes the tests. Currently, the Excel filename and path are configured in the soapui project, however I would like to override the file path and name in the pom. Something like the below

```
<testSuiteProperties>
   <properties>
     <property>file=testdata.xls</property>
   </properties>
</testSuiteProperties>
```

The property name file is not a custom property, instead it is an element within the soapui xml.Snippet of the soapui xml is

```
<con:testStep type="datasource" name="DataSource" id="9422e92f-413b-460f-8381-301f91bdfffa">
        <con:settings/>
        <con:config xsi:type="con:DataSourceStep" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <con:dataSource type="Excel">
                <con:configuration>
                    <file>path/to/the/xls/file</file>
                    <worksheet/>
                    <cell>A2</cell>
                    <ignoreEmpty>false</ignoreEmpty>
                </con:configuration>
            </con:dataSource>
            ... 
          </con:config>
</con:testStep>
```

In the above snippet, I would like to override the value of file element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your pom, you want to use [projectProperties](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html#1-basic-configuration):

```
<projectProperties>
    <value>file=testdata.xls</value>
</projectProperties>
```

Then in your project, in the datasource teststep file, use [property expansion](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html): `path/to/the/xls/${#Project#file}`.

Comment: This is one way to do it and I am aware of the solution that you have provided. By doing so, I would have to modify my soapui xml file to add the expansion property before I check it into my scm repository. Instead, I am actually trying to see if you can directly access the soapui elements and modify the values. Like in the above example, when I specify file=testdata.xls, I am expecting that the value of <file>element in the soapui project will be replaced with the value provided. Similarly if I want to modify the value of <Cell>then I would provide cell=B2.